# R: wordcloud package omitting words below three characters from corpus

Tags: r, tm, word-cloud

When creating a wordcloud using the wordcloud package it seems like the package defaults to omitting words below three characters (such as "tv"). I think this is a feature rather than a bug, but still I could not find an argument that adjusts the minimum character count.

The wordcloud is run against a corpus of words created and preprocessed with the *Corpus()* and *tm_map()* functions from the tm package. I have confirmed that the words in question have not gotten lost when e.g. removing stopwords - they are still in the final corpus on which the *wordcloud()* function is run.

**Reproducible example [edit]**

Real data obviously looks different. However, the lines below replicates the error.

```
customPalette <- brewer.pal(4, "Dark2")

wordVector <- c(rep("tv", 15), rep("computer", 4), rep("phone", 16), rep("tablet",10))
newCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(wordVector))

wordcloud(newCorpus, max.words = 100, scale=c(8,1), random.order = FALSE, random.color = TRUE, colors = customPalette)
```

This creates output:

[image: Wordcloud output]

**Session info:**

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Amazon Linux AMI 2016.09

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] bindrcpp_0.2             zoo_1.8-0                wordcloud_2.5            RColorBrewer_1.1-2       SnowballC_0.5.1          tm_0.7-1                
 [7] NLP_0.1-10               reshape2_1.4.2           lubridate_1.6.0          scales_0.4.1             ggplot2_2.2.1            aws.s3_0.3.3            
[13] githubinstall_0.2.1.9001 aws.signature_0.3.2      RJDBC_0.2-5              rJava_0.9-8              DBI_0.7                  RCurl_1.95-4.8          
[19] bitops_1.0-6             jsonlite_1.5             dplyr_0.7.0              sparklyr_0.5.6           drat_0.1.2               devtools_1.13.2         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] slam_0.1-40       lattice_0.20-34   colorspace_1.3-2  htmltools_0.3.6   yaml_2.1.14       base64enc_0.1-3   rlang_0.1.1       glue_1.1.1       
 [9] withr_1.0.2       dbplyr_1.0.0      bindr_0.1         plyr_1.8.4        stringr_1.2.0     munsell_0.4.3     gtable_0.2.0      memoise_1.1.0    
[17] labeling_0.3      httpuv_1.3.3      parallel_3.3.2    curl_2.6          Rcpp_0.12.11      xtable_1.8-2      backports_1.1.0   config_0.2       
[25] mime_0.5          digest_0.6.12     stringi_1.1.5     shiny_1.0.3       rprojroot_1.2     grid_3.3.2        tools_3.3.2       magrittr_1.5     
[33] lazyeval_0.2.0    tibble_1.3.3      pkgconfig_2.0.1   data.table_1.10.4 xml2_1.1.1        assertthat_0.2.0  httr_1.2.1        rstudioapi_0.6   
[41] R6_2.2.2          git2r_0.18.0
```

Comment: It works for me with a small example including 'TV' as a word.  Might it be because the frequencies are low?  Wordcloud by default ignores words with frequencies less than 3, and you are also limiting it to the top 100 words in your example.  You will need to give us a reproducible example if you still have a problem!

Comment: That's interesting. Will check to see if I can create a reproducible version of the error without sharing the specific dataset. The words in question should clear the word count bar.

Comment: Have now updated with a reproducible example. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears whether using the vector `wordVector` or with the corpus version.  This seems to be intended behaviour - see comment below from the package maintainer.

The following alternative approach works, using the ability of `wordcloud` to take a vector of words and their frequencies separately...

```
worddf <- as.data.frame(table(newCorpus$content))
wordcloud(words = worddf[,1], freq = worddf[,2], max.words = 100, scale=c(8,1), 
          random.order = FALSE, random.color = TRUE, colors = customPalette)
```

[image]

Comment: Per the documentation, if freq is not provided, wordcloud attempts to make some intelligent plotting decisions by removing punctuations and stopwords.

Answer (score 0):

What I have observed is that if your input text has any word with frequency greater than or equal to the default value of min freq, i.e. 3, all other words having freq less than 3 will be ignored.

However, if your input text doesn't have any word with freq >= 3, all words are considered for plotting. So in such cases, always update the min.freq argument and set it to your desired value.